# How to solve this SQL query emp manager relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

1. emp (id, name)
2. emp_manager_rel (emp_id, mngr_id)

[image]

[image]

In the second table `emp_id` and `mngr_id` is the related with `id` column of `emp` table.

We need id, emp name, manager name of respected emp

we tried lot of join and subqueries, but did not get the expected result.

Comment: Tag appropriate database name and your so far developed script you are trying with.

Comment: In general, there is an expectation amongst readers that question authors should try writing some code _before_ asking a question. In the event they write some code but it does not work, they should show that code. Since this is missing that work, it is likely to be put on hold. Thus, although you received a bit of free work this time around, you cannot do this too often without receiving an automated question ban on your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining `emp_manager_rel` table with `emp` table two times based on the id columns, you will get the expected result:

```
SELECT e.id as empid, e.name as empname, 
       m.id as managerid, m.name as managername
FROM emp_manager_rel em
JOIN emp e ON e.id = em.emp_id
JOIN emp m ON m.id = em.mngr_id
```

Comment: This works fine thnak u so much!

Answer (score 1):

This following script will work on MySQL and SQL Server.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.name Employee_Name,C.Name Manager_Name 
FROM Emp A
LEFT JOIN emp_manager_rel B ON A.Id = B.emp_id
INNER JOIN Emp C ON B.mngr_id = C.ID
```